# Unable to build native packages for node

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-gyp, electron-rebuild

So Im running an Electron app that has some native modules of one them being a package called `better-sqlite3`. I run yarn and yarn is able to install all packages without a problem but when it gets to the building steps, everything breaks.

I get a bunch of diffrent `node-gyp` error outputs of which 2 I have been able to save so I can show here here is the important part of the error output for the first error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(67,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install v140 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\bepop\Documents\DeveloperData\Clippy\app\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]`

[Full error](https://pastebin.com/MACaGBtJ)

In terms of this error I've tried doing multiple things such as installing microsoft visual build tools in many diffrent ways such as manually going to their website and downloading the IDE, I've also tried installing the build tools through NPM with:

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

It always succesfully installs the build tools but still it errors out on me, I've also tried editing the npm config with:`npm config set msvs_version 2017`
still doesnt work. I have also tried going to the installation of the Visual Studio and manually checking: "VC++ 2017 version 15.7 v14.14 latest v141 tools"
Also nothing.

I do remember at some point I was able to get everything to build normally with Windows 10 and I never had a problem but not anymore. I've been trying to fix this issue by myself for months now and I've just been sticking on working on the project on my macbook where it never has issues building the `better-sqlite3` package.

1 more thing I have tried is completely wiping my computer from everything and starting fresh because at some point i had changed so many things that I lost track of what I had installed and what I did not.

If I remove the `better-sqlite3` package from the `package.json` file everything runs smoothly and I am able to run my project normally but I need the `better-sqlite3` package. I could use another package but I really shouldnt have to do that, I'd like to get to the bottom of why this i snot building.

Edit:

Updated: I added Microsoft build tools v14.0.23107.0 to my pats variable and now it outputs error:

`C:\Users\bepop\Documents\DeveloperData\Clippy\node_modules\integer\build\integer.vcxproj(21,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

Comment: Is the project opening correctly is VS?

Comment: @Aditya_Anand This project is not open in VS it's just node-gyp trying to build a package

Comment: Check your binding.gyp to specify the cpp version to compile with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue for myself:

1. Delete node modules folder

2. Open PowerShell with admin privileges and run in order

   npm install --global --production --vs2015 --add-python-to-path windows-build-tools

   npm install --global --production --add-python-to-path windows-build-tools node-gyp

3. Go to `~/.npmrc` and make sure these are your settings:

   msvs_version=2015

   python=python2.7

Comment: This are the same steps which i mention in my answer. if you check the link which i mention in answer you will find the same steps.

Comment: These specific steps worked for me I do not see these steps in the exact order in the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

First remove all the visual studio version installed from your system , and also remove the entries from `path` and `system variable` .

and follow the below URL 
 https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#readme

Every thing run fine after removing of `better-sqlite3` this package entry from `package.json` because other packages don't have any native dependency . and this `better-sqlite3` is native module after downloading, this module get build using tool `node-gpy` that will need two things installed on your system i.e. `python` and `visual studio` .

So try to follow the above URL steps.

it will definitely work.

Comment: This didnt work for me but I added a solution that did work thanks for helping!